# Passing data back to a data model file using protocols and delegates

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

[SOLVED] As a beginner, this most likely isn't an optimal or clever solution, however it does what it needs to do. The data from the AddVocabViewController is passed back via this delegate and then inserts a new instance of Vocab into the array in the data model. Also the delegation in the prepare for segue function allowed the data to pass through.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, passNewWordData{
    func passDataBack(data: Vocab){
        vocabBuilder.n1LevelVocab.insert(data, at: vocabBuilder.n1LevelVocab.startIndex)

        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let currentVocabNumber = vocabNumber
            self.vocabBuilder.n1LevelVocab.swapAt(currentVocabNumber, self.vocabBuilder.n1LevelVocab.startIndex)
            self.loadUIN1()
            print(vocabNumber)
        }
    }
```

Original Question is as follows:

I have a class modal view controller that passes data back successfully but I want to insert this data type into an array.

My modal view controller is this:

```
import UIKit

protocol passNewWordData {
    func passDataBack(data: Vocab)
}
//pass back the data using this protocol and calling it as a delegate

 var vocabBuilder1 = VocabBuilder()
class AddVocabularyViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet var modalView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var vocabTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var hiraganaTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var englishTranslationTextField: UITextField!

    
     var delegate: passNewWordData?
    //this is crucial! This is the link between both VCs.

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
    }
    
    @IBAction func addNewWord(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        guard let vocabText = vocabTextField.text, vocabTextField.hasText else {
            print("Error no data")
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Missing Vocabulary Word!", message: "Please fill in the Vocabulary field", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
            present(ac, animated: true)
            return
        }
        
        guard let hiraganaText = hiraganaTextField.text, hiraganaTextField.hasText else {
            print("Error no hiragana entered")
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Missing hiragana!", message: "Please fill in the Hiragana field", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
            present(ac, animated: true)
            return
        }
        guard let englishTranslationText = englishTranslationTextField.text, englishTranslationTextField.hasText else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Missing English Translation!", message: "Please fill in the English Translation field", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
            present(ac, animated: true)
            print("Error no english translation entered.")
            return
        }
        
        //better to have guard lets to handle the data so conditions are correct before passing the data..
        
        let newWord = Vocab(vocabTitle: vocabText, vocabHiragana: hiraganaText, englishTranslation: englishTranslationText, noOfTimesSeen: 0)
        
 
        delegate?.passDataBack(data: newWord)
        print(newWord)
             
    }
```

This prints out the data that's being sent back no problem but what I want to do is add this data to a data model file I made specifically to an array inside it.

```
struct VocabBuilder {
       
    var n1LevelVocab = [Vocab(vocabTitle: "上達", vocabHiragana: "じょうたつ", englishTranslation: "Improvement", noOfTimesSeen: 0),
                      Vocab(vocabTitle: "乗り越える", vocabHiragana: "のりこえる", englishTranslation: "To Push Through", noOfTimesSeen: 0),
                      Vocab(vocabTitle: "耐久性", vocabHiragana: "たいきゅうせい", englishTranslation: "Durability", noOfTimesSeen: 0),]
```

**Things I've tried:**

I tried to make the extension to the the main view controller to receive the data but it won't append the data when I call the functions from the data model to add them.

```
extension ViewController: passNewWordData {

        func passDataBack(data: Vocab) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
            self.vocabInfo.n1LevelVocab.append(data)
        //vocabInfo is calling the VocabBuilder Struct.


            //need to append this data to the newWord variable then send that back to the n1VocabArray in the dataModel.
            
            print(data)
            
        }
    
    }
```

I tested out inside the data model appending a new Vocab type and it does append an extra item to the array there, but how do I get that data from my modal view controller all the way back to that struct? Would I need to create an extension to handle the data from the protocol in my data model itself? Most examples are just passing directly into the view controller.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The extension to `ViewController` you have shown already seems to add the new word to the array.  Are you trying to access the updated `VocabBuilder`  somewhere else?  Be aware that Swift structs are value types and updating one instance will not update another instance .  Model objects are typically classes not structs so they are reference types and you can have a single instance referenced in multiple places.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey thanks for your reply. I am accessing the VocabBuilder when I press a button to go through an array which moves through each Vocab item inside it. After looking into it more, the main problem is that the extension in the view controller  is not triggering after using some breakpoints and printing if the data was added to the array but nothing. Also thanks for reminding me to read more about value and reference types...I still get confused about which to use. I changed my VocabBuilder to a class instead of struct to allow it to be referenced.

Comment: Make sure you are setting the delegate correctly on the correct instance of your class

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey Paul, thanks so much for your advice, it was the delegates which weren't being passed correctly. I looked at the problem a different way and called the delegate in the View Controller class, added the protocol stub and passed the data that way to my data model swift file. Learnt a lot about protocols and delegates these last few days!